# What are the rights of converts on muslim ummah?

Tags: hadith, conversion, fard, human-rights

As converter have a great importance in Islam  Prophet Muhammad (SAW) advised to  financially help them with zakat so that they may not backup from there faith due to financial issues. What other rights they have? explain according to Islam?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converts do not have any other special rights above that of other common Muslims, At the beginning of Islam everyone was a convert before the sahaba gave birth to children.